# Leaflet Markercluster - tooltip on hover issue

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, markerclusterer

I'm a newbie of javascript, trying to build an interactive map online, where some events should be triggered by clicking on markers and some just by hovering them. 
Managed to have the click part working, but, because of Markercluster plugin, I'm not sure where to use onEachFeature function for having the tooltip opened by hover a single marker.
Anyone please can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
var geoJsonFeature = {
  type: 'FeatureCollection',
  features: 
   [
    {
    type: 'Feature',
    properties: {
        title: 'Title',
        page: 'some.html',
        'marker-color': '#000000',
        zoom: 7
    },
    geometry: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [12.583745,55.6750803]
    }
},
...
};

// access to mapbox api
L.mapbox.accessToken ='...';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'example1234').setView([34, -37], 3);

function getTitle(marker) {
    return marker.feature.properties.title;
};

function getPage(marker) {
    return marker.feature.properties.page;
};

var markerGroup = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({showCoverageOnHover:false});

var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(geoJsonFeature, {
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    var popupContent = getTitle(marker);
    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
  }
});

markerGroup.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);

map.addLayer(markerGroup);

markerGroup.on('click', function(ev) {
  var marker = ev.layer;

  marker.on('click', function(ev) {
    if(map.getZoom() > marker.feature.properties.zoom) {
        map.setView(ev.latlng, map.getZoom());   
    } 
    else {
        map.setView(ev.latlng, marker.feature.properties.zoom);
    }
   });
  });
});

geoJsonLayer.on('mouseover', function(e) {
  e.layer.openPopup();
});

geoJsonLayer.on('mouseout', function(e) {
  e.layer.closePopup();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the onEachFeature option to get the individual markers and bind handlers to the mouseover and mouseout events:

```
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
  layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.title);
  layer.on("mouseover", function () {
    layer.openPopup();
  });
  layer.on("mouseout", function () {
    layer.closePopup();
  });
}
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/hfjOWv3uCBFawDGqR3Ue?p=preview

Note: i'm not using ClusterMarker in this example but it should work just fine when using ClusterMarker

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly.
For integrate it with Markercluster, I add "onEachFeature" to layer in which I stored the GeoJson data, that I later add to Markergroup and than again to the map.

    var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(geoJsonFeature, {
     onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
      layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.title);
      layer.on("mouseover", function () {
        layer.openPopup();
       });
       layer.on("mouseout", function () {
        layer.closePopup();
       });
     }
    });

Comment: I wish that I could figure out how to do this without `geoJson`  :-(   I am totally stuck on generating a (multi-line) tooltip for a Leaflet map cluster. So stuck that I don't even have any code which I could post.